# writing more complex math input to fish shell

Tags: linux, shell, calculator, fish

The fish documentation explains that the `math` command is essentially a thin wrapper to `bc`. The `bc` documentation has further info about more complex ops:

> If bc is invoked with the -l option, a math library is preloaded and the default scale is set to 20. The math functions will calculate their results to the scale set at the time of their call. The math library defines the following functions:
>
> s (x)
>       The sine of x, x is in radians.
>   c (x)
>       The cosine of x, x is in radians.
>   a (x)
>       The arctangent of x, arctangent returns radians.
>   l (x)
>       The natural logarithm of x.
>   e (x)
>       The exponential function of raising e to the value x.
>   j (n,x)
>       The bessel function of integer order n of x.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `math`: `math -l l(16)/l(2)`, for example, gets interpreted as a command substitution, and `math "-l l(16)/l(2)"` and `math -l "l(16)/l(2)"` are interpreted erroneously also.

Is there a nice way to input this quickly and efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to your fish configuration:

```
function bc; command bc -l $argv; end
```

Since `math` calls `bc`, this will take care or your issue.

Comment: The first `bc` is treated as a function name, while `command bc` is the actual program outside of the scope of the function. Am I reading that right?

Comment: exactly so ....

Comment: In fish 3.0.2 I see `math` is a builtin, no longer affected by this definition.
Anyway, such alias will get you used to running `math` and `bc` in a way that won't work for others / on other machines.  I recommend either directly running `echo 'l(16)/l(2)' | bc -l`, or making a function with different name e.g. `mathl`.